# Using multiple instances of the same plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just implemented a plugin named `flip-carousel.js` into my website. The following is a sample of the implementation.

[sample implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/7bvpp826/3/)

The problem is I want to have multiple instances of the same plugin. Initialization of the plugin is as following.

```
$('article').flipcarousel({
    pagination: false,
    loader: true,
    itemsperpage: 3,
    randomizer: 0.7
});
```

For multiple instances I used class instead of elements. The plugin takes the element list and change them to the effect using injected elements + the content in the html tags I have. The following is the implementation of multiple instances.

```
var roomTypes = hotelData.getSelectedRoomTypeIds();
roomTypes.forEach(function(e){
    if($('.flip_article_' + e.toString()).length > 0){
        $('.flip_article_' + e.toString()).flipcarousel({
            pagination: false,
            loader: true,
            itemsperpage: 3,
            randomizer: 0.7
        });
    }
})
```

I initially have created a set of elements with the given class names ( `'.flip_article_' + e.toString()` ). For an example a class name can be `flip_article_1210`.

Then I loop through the elements and init the plugin. The problem is that, the first carousel gets initialized with no problems but from the second set of elements although the carousel is intialized, there are no element items in it. I tried reading the plugin code to modify, but couldn't get an idea.

first thought I got is that the plugin uses a parent class named `flip-carousel` and append everything to it, where if I could have unique parent class for each carousel I create, the rest would work! but it would not work since the other methods are dependent of it.

I've linked the source of the plugin in the following url. if any one could help me on this it would be a great help.

[plugin source.](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-CSS3-Carousel-Plugin-with-Content-Flipping-Effects-Flip-Carousel/flip-carousel.js)

Comment: can you reproduce the error in a fiddle?

Comment: this is the updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/7bvpp826/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the plugin a little bit and its working fine now.

on line number 73 in [this](https://github.com/herrethan/flipcarousel/blob/master/flip-carousel.js) file

change `$card = $('.card');` to `$card = $container.parent().find('.card');`

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/7bvpp826/8/)

**UPDATE**

You should initialize the plugin like this

```
$('#flip1 article').flipcarousel({
    pagination: true,
    loader: true,
    itemsperpage: 3,
    randomizer: 0.7
});

$('#flip2 article').flipcarousel({
    pagination: true,
    loader: true,
    itemsperpage: 3,
    randomizer: 0.7
});
```

Comment: This makes them load the cards correctly but there is a small issue with the controls! initially the controls in the second set of cards are hidden. and when I manually show them, the controls don't work!

Comment: its working perfectly in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/7bvpp826/8/embedded/result/)